# Issue in REST URL delimiters

Tags: java, rest, url, jakarta-ee, delimiter

I have one REST based java module running on tomcat and i am calling below URL. when i call below URL it is working fine:

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx/emp/salary?query=(FirstName startswith anil)
```

Now i want multi query support in URL on basis of `&` delimiter and for that i have done some code changes as below. basically split string on basis of `&`

```
String[] fArray = filterstr.split("&");

https://xx.xx.xx.xx/emp/salary?query=(FirstName startswith anil%26LastName startswith singh)
```

`%26` is basically `&`

And using above URL its also working fine.

The problem is, in our database we are also supporting firstname as `"anil&kumar"`, Means using other interfaces admin can create user firstname with all delimiters.

so now when you call first URL with: `query=(FirstName startswith anil%26kumar)`, it is failing because our split code breaks this user into 2 parts `anil`, `kumar`. however it should be one so that it can match in DB.

So any thought how i can solve this issue.

when i have below string in query param then i am able to separate out using split method with `&` and i get 2 parts

```
 query= (FirstName startswith anil&LastName startswith singh)
```

- 1st part: `FirstName startswith anil`
- 2nd part: `LastName startswith singh`

but lets have query param as,

```
query= (FirstName startswith bob&smith&LastName startswith singh)
```

now using split it separates `bob&smith` into 2 parts (`bob` , `smith`) but i don't want because user is `bob&smith`. 
it is returning after split-

```
[FirstName startswith bob, smith, LastName startswith singh]
```

want better solution. 1st, 2nd query both should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx/emp/salary?query=(FirstName=bob%26smith&LastName=singh)
```

this should work fine.
i tried this on my machine ...working fine for me

And If your Data Base is using a split method on names then do it like this

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx/emp/salary?query=(FirstName=bob|smith&LastName=singh)
```

this is a PIPE sign, split on that